# Moving multiple MySQL tables to ElasticSearch in the same index

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, lucene, logstash

I am migrating my database to ElasticSearch. Its current size is less than 3G, and since many fields are common across tables, I have decided to use a single index to store them.

Here's my Logstash configuration:

```
input {
  jdbc { 
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cinestop?
useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
    jdbc_user => "root"
    jdbc_password => "abc"
    # The path to our downloaded jdbc driver
    jdbc_driver_library => 
"/home/limafoxtrottango/Downloads/elasticsearch-jdbc-2.3.4.0/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
statement => "SELECT * FROM media_adult"
       }
}
output {
  stdout { codec => json_lines }
  elasticsearch {
  "hosts" => "localhost:9200"
  "index" => "cinestop"
  "document_type" => "media_adult"
       }
}
```

I have imported a previous table (that had some common fields) with this table. Now, I get the following error:

```
"Rejecting mapping update to [cinestop] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [media_adult, media_id]"}}}}
```

I have read the documentation, and it mentions that ES won't let you have multiple fields with different types in the same index, due to how the mapping is done in Apache Lucene. But even if I do

```
SELECT adult FROM media_adult
```

in the config file (the resulting table won't have any common fields with the previously imported table), the error does not go away.

Can someone please tell me what is it that I am doing wrong? Should I create a separate index for each type?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Elasticsearch are you using? Multiple types in a single index is not allowed starting from version 6.

Comment: Yes, in-fact, I am using a version above that. I read that it is not allowed. So, should I do an index per table? Won't that be inefficient?

Comment: Depends on what your use case is, if you're going to be doing SQL type joins then there will be a performance hit

Comment: I will. Have around 20 tables. Can you suggest something?

Comment: You could use elasticsearch version 5.5, where you can have multiple types in an index, to move data then update to latest when you are done. But be warned they plan to drop support in version 7. Other option is to use nested documents, where you will have to join all tables then write, in this case the queries you would write will get complicated. So you need to choose based on an optimal combination of how this will evolve and how much you want to spend on dev effort down the road.

Comment: You mean, join all the 20 tables, and store it as a single index in ES, right? Thanks for the tip btw.

Comment: Yes if they are all related